# Boolean query equals works as like

Tags: postgresql, solr, booleanquery

I'm trying to prepare some boolean query for SOLR engine to find some docs with specific locality field. Results that I get seems to be very weird. I cannot give exactly the same code I use because of security policy in my company but trying to simplify this query:

```
+(ddm/10973/locality_pl_PL:Gdańsk)
```

And this query return results as expected with Gdańsk city. But when I add some another condition like this:

```
+(+(ddm/10973/locality_pl_PL:Gdańsk)+(status:0))
```

In my results I get docs with city Gdańsk and Gdańsk-Wrzeszcz. Suddenly ":" seems to work as a 'like' not 'equals' as expected.
Does somebody know what could be the reason?

Comment: That would depends on the definition of the field "ddm/10973/locality_pl_PL". If the field has a tokenizer attached, it's probably splitting the content into two separate tokens based on `-`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know where to look for solution